# sync version management in npm and git

Tags: node.js, git, npm, version-control

I have a npm project with a git repository in the same project environment.
With **git** I do an version upgrade with commits and tags:

```
$ git commit -m 'my recent repo changes'    
$ git tag v1.0.1
```

With **npm** I can bump my package version with:

```
$ npm version patch -m 'my recent repo changes'
```

But if I try this with changed files, npm throws an error: *git working directory is not clean.*
In the end I need to add and commit my changes with git, but the npm package version is still the same.

Is it possible to synchronize the versions of the npm project inside of my git repo? What is the best practice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do need to **keep git repo working directory clean before bumping the `package.json` version**.

And it's also unnecessary to update the version in `package.json` file and add tag manually.

The workflow should be:

- **Make changes for your project**

  You can modify your project and it's unnecessary to update the version in `package.json`manually.
- **Commit changes**

  After modification, commit the changes you made by `git commit -am 'message'`.
- **Bump the version**

  Then bump the version automatically by `npm version patch -m 'message'`. And it will create a new commit for the changes of `package.json` version, and add the tag with the new version at the same time.

  You can double check for the new commit by showing the commit history (such as use the command `gitk --all`).

Comment: But then I got two commits with the same content.

Comment: The output just shows the difference of my package.json file: -1.0.0; +1.0.1. But my log says, there are two commits: one with a tag and the other one without. Isnt there a better solution?

Comment: So the commit without tag should be the changes you committed manually. And for next time, just let the version updated automatically by `npm version patch`.